# vim mapping ctrl-;

Tags: vim, mapping, ctrl

In my case the move-right button is <kbd>;</kbd>

I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> to move the cursor 7 characters to the right.
I've tried the below .vimrc mapping, but it doesn't work:

`nmap <c-;> 7;`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Like previous comment says, it seems that ";" cannot be in the form `<C-;>`.

You can test typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> + key sequence.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> gives only `;` whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> give `^L`.

So I suppose that vim **cannot** recognize `<C-;>`.

You have some more information on the key codes help pages:

```
:help keycodes
:help <C-
```

Comment: Using the ctrl+v trick, I realized that `<M-;>` works just fine, so that could be a potential workaround.

Comment: For some reason when I type <C-;> it registers as an <esc>

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure, but it might be because `<C-;>` does not map to an ASCII character. Only `@`, `A-Z`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^` and `_` map to ASCII characters (0 through 31 respectively) when combined with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

**EDIT**

I did some searching and found [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/unable-to-map-ctrl-1-td22818782.html). In it, it is said that `gvim.exe` works the way I suggest: only use valid control characters, no other. Interestingly `vim.exe` works differently and you can do the mapping you want.

Answer (score 6):

As others said `<c-;>`  can't be mapped. 
The best solution is:

```
nmap <C-l> 7l
nmap <C-h> 7h
```

You can remap the regular cursor keys instead.
something like this also would work:

```
nmap <C-Right> 7l
nmap <C-Left> 7h
```

Other side example for resizing windows:

```
" resize horzontal split window
nmap <C-Up> <C-W>-<C-W>-
nmap <C-Down> <C-W>+<C-W>+
" resize vertical split window
nmap <C-Right> <C-W>><C-W>>
nmap <C-Left> <C-W><<C-W><
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hack your keyboard by using sxhkd + xkvbd. Just to give you an idea I was able to map C-LefMouse so my system recognize as if it was MiddleMouse:

```
# put this in your sxhkdrc
ctrl + button1
    xvkbd -no-jump-pointer -xsendevent -text '\m2'
```

~/.config/nvim/lua/core/utils

```
local M = {}

-- https://blog.devgenius.io/create-custom-keymaps-in-neovim-with-lua-d1167de0f2c2
-- https://oroques.dev/notes/neovim-init/
M.map = function(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
    local options = { noremap = true }
    if opts then
        options = vim.tbl_extend("force", options, opts)
    end
    vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, lhs, rhs, options)
end
return M
```

In our mappings.lua

```
local map = require('core.utils').map

-- copy to the primary selection on mouse release
map("v", "<LeftRelease>", '"*y')
map("i", "<C-MiddleMouse>", '<C-o>"*p')
map("n", "<C-MiddleMouse>", '"*p')
```

The idea is to make nvim recognize your Ctrl+; as if it was something it can handle, similarly as I did with this primary selection solution. Eventually, these ideas could help someone figure out solutions for other issues.

Answer (score 0):

In KDE konsole terminal, you can add key bindings.

terminal right click menu --> Edit Current Profile --> keyboard --> Edit

I have added a value like this:

```
Key Combination =>  ;+Ctrl  
Output          =>  \E[9;8~
```

then you can check the value with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> in termnal.
if successfully printed `^[[9;8~` then you can use the value in vim key bindings something like this

```
inoremap  ^[[9;8~  <esc>A;
```

you also need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> for the value after inoremap