# what's the plus and minus key symbol in vim

Tags: vim

I known the keypad is KPlus and KMinus.

i'm try to use **`<C-->`** and **`<C-+>`** to define the  key map but it didn't work. 
can you known the origin answer?
help me. 
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that what you're after is impossible because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> doesn't map to an ASCII character. Here's why, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101559/578288):

> I am not sure, but it might be because `<C-;>` does not map to an ASCII character. Only `@`, `A-Z`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^` and `_` map to ASCII characters (0 through 31 respectively) when combined with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/EZT_Q0YRmAM) is a long talk about the same issue:

> In many cases, Ctrl + minus produces the same code as Ctrl + underscore 
>   (.  You might try mapping that instead.  Works here under rxvt-unicode 
>   with a U.S. keyboard:
>
> map  {rhs}
>
> It's also triggered for Ctrl + slash.  So, you can't map these to 
>   different {rhs}'s: `<C--> = <C-_> = <C-/>`

I have tried and for me it works. So you can make it work, but `c-_` and `c-/` will also be mapped to that. You can give it a try:

`:map <C-_> :echo "hello"<CR>`