# vim automaticly replace . with -> in cpp

Tags: c++, vim

Eclipse cdt has a feature I really like, it automaticly converts . to -> if it is used on a pointer. Since on a european keyboard, its  a pain to have to type -> all the time.
So basicly is there a plugin or a way that recognozes that -> is used on a pointer and automaticly converts it in edit mode?
Or if that isn't possible, is there at least a way to just press c-. or altgr-. and have it autmaticly type a -> when in insert mode?

Comment: How about `inoremap .. ->`? If you press `.` twice, vim replaces it with `->`. `..` isn't really used too much in C++. Maybe only with varargs.

Comment: @geza ... is used a lot with variadic templates. I write them all the time on my day job.

Comment: @n.m.: me too, I forgot about them :) adding a `inoremap ... ...` maybe solves this issue, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <C-p> ->
```

This will insert `->` whenever you hit `CTRL+p`

Thanks to Amadeus for pointing out this `<C-whatever>` doesn't work with the period key.

Comment: Vim does not seem to recognize <CTRL .> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101253/vim-mapping-ctrl

Comment: Sorry, Amadeus, I had originally tested this with <C-r> thinking it didn't matter but you're right, you need to use another key. I deleted my comment when I realized.

Comment: unfortunately I use a plugin called CtrlP. Seams really strange that it wouldn't work with .

Comment: You can always substitute any letter for the 'p' and it'll work.

Comment: I would highly recommend not remapping `<C-p>`, as you lose one of the insert-mode completion triggers.